# Trying to crawl some data on Google Sheets but getting beat by XPath

Tags: html, xml, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to make a sheet for study purposes on stock market, and I'm using this website to get the data from. Taking **[this](https://statusinvest.com.br/acoes/abev3)** stock as example.

My goals here are:

1. I want to grab some of the indicators from **[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Szn1.png)** div area (such as P/L, LPA, M. LÍQUIDA, and others);
2. And some of the numbers from **[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdXi6.png)** tables's first column (such as row 11, 15, and others).

My issues:

1. I'm not being able to fetch the data that I want from the div with the IMPORTXML function, neither with copying the XPath nor trying to find a specific class name to find a match.
2. I'm being able to fetch the specific number that I want, but it's returning 3 different values from 3 different rows (I want only the first one), due the XPath that I'm using `//table/tbody/tr[11]/td[2]/span`.

There's 2 more tables down the page that uses the same XPath, and the function is returning the values from row #11 of the other tables, as you can see **[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BdUO.png)**. The only thing that makes the 3 different from one another it's their divs, but I'm not being able to figure out how to manipulate these divs. There's any way to fix this or any function that automatically deletes the other 2 rows?

Can someone give me a light? :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's almost always easier to find the values you need by a reference. This should work to get the `20,76` from the first table

```
(//*[contains(text(), 'P/L')]/following::strong)[1]
```

As far as the second table goes, this should get `52.562,18 M`

```
(//span[contains(text(), 'Receita Líquida')]/following::td)[1]
```

If you need to get different columns, you can just pass a higher index, this will return `-0,07%` for instance.

```
(//span[contains(text(), 'Receita Líquida')]/following::td)[5]
```

I also highly recommend getting some sort of xpath tester addon for your browser to play around with these if you don't already have one. I use ChroPath:

Firefox - 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/chropath-for-firefox/

Chrome - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chropath/ljngjbnaijcbncmcnjfhigebomdlkcjo?hl=en-US

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I couldn't make your paths work here, were you able to make them work on Google Sheets?

Comment: @ThiagoGomes - Check out my update to the first one. It seems like sheets was having trouble picking up the `h3` tag and I have no clue why. I didn't have any problems getting the second two to work.

Comment: Could you share your test sheet with me? I think I'm using the parentheses the wrong way. Edit: Nevermind, I figured out how to make them work. Thank you very much, @scilence!